# Hibernate not inserting rows

Tags: mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, sql-insert, composite-primary-key

I able to generate the schema but when I try to insert, nothing seems to be happening. It won't print anything in the logs either. My Phone table primary key is a composite key consisting of phoneNumber and foreign key id.

I have my classes as below

**Student.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Student implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String fName;

private String lName;

private String mname;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Set<Phone> phones;

/**
 * @return the fName
 */
public String getfName() {
    return fName;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @return the lName
 */
public String getlName() {
    return lName;
}

/**
 * @return the mname
 */
public String getMname() {
    return mname;
}

/**
 * @return the phones
 */
public Set<Phone> getPhones() {
    return phones;
}

/**
 * @param fName
 *            the fName to set
 */
public void setfName(final String fName) {
    this.fName = fName;
}

/**
 * @param id
 *            the id to set
 */
public void setId(final int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @param lName
 *            the lName to set
 */
public void setlName(final String lName) {
    this.lName = lName;
}

/**
 * @param mname
 *            the mname to set
 */
public void setMname(final String mname) {
    this.mname = mname;
}

/**
 * @param phones
 *            the phones to set
 */
public void setPhones(final Set<Phone> phones) {
    this.phones = phones;
}

}
```

**Phone.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@IdClass(PhonePK.class)
@Entity
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Phone implements Serializable {

@Id
private String phoneNumber;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Student student;

private String color;

/**
 * @return the color
 */
public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

/**
 * @return the phoneNumber
 */
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

/**
 * @return the student
 */
public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

/**
 * @param color
 *            the color to set
 */
public void setColor(final String color) {
    this.color = color;
}

/**
 * @param phoneNumber
 *            the phoneNumber to set
 */
public void setPhoneNumber(final String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

/**
 * @param student
 *            the student to set
 */
public void setStudent(final Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

}
```

**PhonePK.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PhonePK implements Serializable {

private String phoneNumber;

private Student student;

/**
 * @return the phoneNumber
 */
public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return phoneNumber;
}

/**
 * @return the student
 */
public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
}

/**
 * @param phoneNumber
 *            the phoneNumber to set
 */
public void setPhoneNumber(final String phoneNumber) {
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

/**
 * @param student
 *            the student to set
 */
public void setStudent(final Student student) {
    this.student = student;
}

}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">pwd</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Main.java**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Main {

   public static void main(final String args[]) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Student.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Phone.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(PhonePK.class);
    configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Student student = new Student();
    student.setfName("Bob");
    student.setlName("Buster");
    Set<Phone> phones = new LinkedHashSet<Phone>();
    Phone ph1 = new Phone();
    ph1.setColor("Black");
    ph1.setPhoneNumber("1111111111");

    Phone ph2 = new Phone();
    ph2.setColor("Blue");
    ph2.setPhoneNumber("2222222222");
    phones.add(ph1);
    phones.add(ph2);

    student.setPhones(phones);
    session.save(student);
 }
}
```

**console output:**

```
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.2.Final}
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver     
resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace    
http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead.    
Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM   
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl    
configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM   
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl    
configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM   
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl   
 configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM   
 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl  
configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL   
[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test]
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:42 AM   
org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl   
configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=user, password=****}
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:43 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:44 AM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
WARN: HHH000038: Composite-id class does not override equals(): PhonePK
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:44 AM org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass checkCompositeIdentifier
WARN: HHH000039: Composite-id class does not override hashCode(): PhonePK

Jun 29, 2013 10:47:44 AM   
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:44 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory   
<init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:44 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: alter table Phone drop foreign key FK_aoj0eivd0ap3drxnoyk4xj10q
Hibernate: drop table if exists Phone
Hibernate: drop table if exists Student
Hibernate: create table Phone (phoneNumber varchar(255) not null, color varchar(255),    
id integer not null, primary key (phoneNumber, id))
Hibernate: create table Student (id integer not null auto_increment, fName     
varchar(255), lName varchar(255), mname varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table Phone add index FK_aoj0eivd0ap3drxnoyk4xj10q (id), add    
constraint FK_aoj0eivd0ap3drxnoyk4xj10q foreign key (id) references Student (id)
Jun 29, 2013 10:47:45 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000230: Schema export complete
Hibernate: insert into Student (fName, lName, mname) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select phone_.phoneNumber, phone_.id, phone_.color as color2_0_ from Phone     
phone_ where phone_.phoneNumber=? and phone_.id=?
Hibernate: select phone_.phoneNumber, phone_.id, phone_.color as color2_0_ from Phone             
phone_ where phone_.phoneNumber=? and phone_.id=?
```

Comment: Had the same error message, but in my case @IdClass(XXX.class) was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with below:

```
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(student);
        transaction.commit();
        assertTrue(true); 
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

Since you are not committing the transactions, you see that everything goes fine in logs but operations performed were not committed.

Comment: Thanks.. I did that and it says the below now.                              at Main.main(Main.java:48)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' cannot be null

Comment: Can you try running the query generated by hibernate directly in mysql and check if you see any error?

Comment: The way I have the schema, I have id column in Phone table as both primary key and foreign key to Student table and its failing while trying to perform an insert. How can I get this to work? Below is from logs.

Comment: insert into Student (fName, lName, mname) values (?, ?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - Bob
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - Buster
binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - <null>

Comment: insert into Phone (color, phoneNumber, id) values (?, ?, ?)
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - Black
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - 1111111111
binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - <null>

SqlExceptionHelper:145 - SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
SqlExceptionHelper:147 - Column 'id' cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

You finally need to [commit](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-workingpersistence):

```
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am getting  anew error now                                                 at Main.main(Main.java:48)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' cannot be null